How to resolve enum name conflict in Juila?
The code below fails
@enum Align top right bottom left
@enum Direction up right down left

print(left)

Ideally without using ugly prefixed names like align_left and direction_left.

I'm not sure what you're hoping for.  There is no magic.  Prefixes are the answer.

@TimRoberts It's surprised me that julia founded on multiple dispatch, and can't handle such a simple case of value overload. It's basically as if you had to use integer_multiply(1, 2) and float_multiply(1.0, 2.0). I was hoping that it would be better.

Agree with @TimRoberts. I'm also not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here. You're creating conflicting type assertions - you wouldn't be able to say left::Int = 1 and left::Float64 = 1.0 and expect it to not throw an error.

C programmers often do things like @enum align alTop alRight alBottom alLeft and @enum Direction dirUp dirRight dirDown dirLeft.  What you're asking is just impossible.  There is no way to determine from left which one was intended.

@TimRoberts it is possible, same way as multiple dispatch works, it's just Julia Language made wrong design choice with enums, after asking question, I later found this exact case mentioned by one of Julia creators mentioning that current implementation enum is not good and in Julia v2 they may try to do it better.

Have you tried EnumX.jl? It exports a macro @enumx which allows you to easily declare enums in tiny little packages. That way, you can have Direction.left and Align.left mean different things (and be of different types).
From the package documentation:
julia> using EnumX

julia> @enumx Fruit Apple Banana

julia> Fruit.Apple
Fruit.Apple = 0

julia> Fruit.Banana
Fruit.Banana = 1

So your use case would be:
using EnumX

@enumx Align begin
    top
    right
    bottom
    left
end

@enumx Direction begin
    up
    down
    left
    right
end

Direction.left == Align.left  # false

You can then dispatch on types Direction.T and Align.T:
julia> Direction.T
Enum type Direction.T <: Enum{Int32} with 4 instances:
 Direction.up    = 0
 Direction.down  = 1
 Direction.left  = 2
 Direction.right = 3

julia> typeof(Direction.left) == Direction.T
true

julia> function which_hand(dir::Direction.T)
           dir == Direction.left && return ""
           dir == Direction.right && return "✋"
           return ""
       end
which_hand (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function which_hand(align::Align.T)
           align == Align.left && return ""
           align == Align.right && return ""
           return ""
       end
which_hand (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> which_hand(Direction.left)
""

julia> which_hand(Align.top)
""


Thanks, not ideal, but tolerable.
