Symbol enum in Julia?
I would like to avoid using ugly prefixed enum names like direction_right, wonder if it's possible to use symbolic enum names?
The problem, code below won't work because of enum conflict names
@enum Align top right bottom left
@enum Direction up right down left

function play(d::Direction)
  print(d)
end

play(right)

Could something like that be used instead?
@enum Align :top :right :bottom :left
@enum Direction :up :right :down :left

function play(d::Direction)
  print(d)
end

play(:right)

I would like to have type safety, and specify Direction type for argument of play.

This appears to be the same as the other question with a slightly different symbolic suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78526825/how-to-resolve-enum-name-conflict-in-juila. As noted in the discussion over there, you're creating conflicting type assertions, and symbolic names won't help with that.

You could use Symbols combined with Val and hence be able to dispatch on type (or on value too if needed)
const Direction = Union{[Val{d} for d in [:up, :right, :down, :left]]...}
function direct(d::Direction)
   println(typeof{d})
end
direct(s::Symbol)=direct(Val{s}())

Now you can do:
julia> direct(:up)
Val{:up}

julia> direct(:up1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching direct(::Val{:up1})


Nice, thanks. Do you know if there's any drawback of this approach, like slower performance or some complications?

This approach is fast once Val{:symbol}() has been created. It uses types for multiple dispatch so is as good as any other Julia code. Hence you can use it in your production code.
